# Poles and branch cut of a complex function defined via an integral

Tags: complex-analysis

My complex analysis is a bit rusty, and I would like to better understand the "paradox" described below.

Let me define the function
$$f(z) := \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{(y+z)^2},$$
which is defined for $z\in \mathbb C\backslash [-1,0]$, as otherwise the integral does not converge.

However, this integral is simple enough and can be computed explicitly for $z\in \mathbb C\backslash [-1,0]$ and gives
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{(y+z)^2}=\frac{1}{z(1+z)}.$$
My confusion comes from the fact that from the definition of $f$, I would have expected that it has a branch cut on the interval $[-1,0]$, but the integral seems naively well-defined but at the two points $z=0$ and $z=-1$ where it has simple poles... (Even evaluating the integral numerically with Mathematica, you don't find a discontinuity as $z$ crosses the "cut" from positive to negative imaginary part.)

What have I missed? Is it just that the function $f(z)$ can be analytically continued but at the two poles, and that the branch cut is just due to a bad parametrization of $f$? If so, another naive question: why can we remove the branch cut but not the poles at the two ends of the interval? What is so specific about them?

Comment: Shouldn't the domain of $f$ be $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,0]$?

Comment: Yes, obviously... my bad.

Comment: because the integrand is analytic, you can deform the original integration path (here a segment) into any other Jordan arc say that keeps the same ends (so get local analytic continuation to $\mathbb C -{0,1}$), while if you rotate through either of the end points, the argument doesn't change because of the square in the denominator (as its residue is zero), so the local extensions patch well and you get a global extension; if you would integrate $\frac{1}{y+z}$ you would indeed get branches

Comment: @Conrad I must confess that your explanation is quite obscure to me, as I said, my complex analysis is quite rusty. Would you mind expanding this comment as an answer (and explain in more detail what a local expansion patch is, and why the $1/(y+z)$ is so different)? I would be happy to accept that as an answer

Comment: Just because some method of calculating a function fails to converge at certain points does not mean that the function cannot extended analytically there. The standard definition of the factorial only works for natural numbers. Yet the factorial function can be extended to the entire complex plane except for the negative integers, where it has poles. The integral definition of $f$ fails when $z \in [-1,0]$ but $f$ still analytically extends to $(-1,0)$ with only $-1$ and $0$ being poles. In fact, if you use the Cauchy Principle Value, even the integral definition works for $x \in (-1,0)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand that one can analytically continue $f$. Thanks to Conrad, I also understand why you can't move the position of the poles. What is still somewhat unclear is why you can patch the analytic continuation coming from above and below the line $[-1,0]$ without introducing a cut (i.e., be sure that the function is not multivalued, as it would happen if the exponent was 1 and not 2 in the integral definition).Also, I am interested in a more complicated functional definition of a function, so a quite general answer (not using the final evaluation of the integral) would be nice